# Using @font-face with a font embedded in Web Control Library

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, vb.net, fonts

I have a problem embedding several font files in a Web Control Library. All the questions I've seen asked here are for fonts residing in the client application.

I'm developing a small Web Control Library for work, which get's referenced as a DLL in client Web Projects. In my DLL I'm registering font-awesome.css as a WebResource

```vb
<Assembly: WebResource(ResourceRegistrar.FONTAWESOME_STYLE_RESOURCE, "text/css")> 

Public Class ResourceRegistrar

    Public Const FONTAWESOME_STYLE_RESOURCE As String = "MyCompany.Web.font-awesome.css"

    Public Shared Sub RegisterFontAwesome(control As Control)
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = control.Page.ClientScript

        Dim stylesheetResourceBlock As String = "<link href='" + cs.GetWebResourceUrl(GetType(ResourceRegistrar), FONTAWESOME_STYLE_RESOURCE) + "' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />"

        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(ResourceRegistrar), FONTAWESOME_STYLE_RESOURCE, stylesheetResourceBlock, False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

FontAwesome get's loaded fine but in the css it defines a font-face that references the fonts packaged in the DLL along with font-awesome.css

```
/*!
 *  Font Awesome 4.1.0 by @davegandy - http://fontawesome.io - @fontawesome
 *  License - http://fontawesome.io/license (Font: SIL OFL 1.1, CSS: MIT License)
 */
/* FONT PATH
 * -------------------------- */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/Styles/Shared/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('/Styles/Shared/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('/Styles/Shared/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'),
       url('/Styles/Shared/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), 
       url('/Styles/Shared/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

}

When the css get's loaded on the client application's page it's expecting to load these fonts based on the client application's folder structure, and not the DLL. The result is a 404 error from the browser when it tries to load these fonts.

How can I package fonts and a css file referencing these fonts in a Web Control Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to include the PerformSubstitution attribute on the assembly declaration and set it to true. Then in the css file that was referencing the font I used code blocks to include the right url.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('<%=WebResource("MyCompany.Web.fontawesome-webfont.woff")%>')    format('woff');
  src: url('<%=WebResource("MyCompany.Web.fontawesome-webfont.otf")%>') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('<%=WebResource("MyCompany.Web.fontawesome-webfont.ttf")%>') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

}